# python Tensorflow ImportError

Tags: python, tensorflow

Please help me with this error:

> import tensorflow as tf Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
>   line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 52, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please try to explain your problem clearly and add your minimal code. It will help others to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try that：

1. Confirm the python interpreter path, is anaconda or system python?
2. export python library `export PYTHONPATH=xxxxx:$PYTHONPATH` to solve some lib couldn't find before execute a python script in terminal.

If you following two step, above troubles could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Before importing TensorFlow, you need to install TensorFlow on Python 3.6.
Firstly, I assumed that you use the Windows operating system because you did not explain any information about your computer.
Open the Anaconda prompt, install TensorFlow with this command:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```

If everything installs successfully, you can import the TensorFlow library in Python.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```